# jQuery: height difference for scrollTop and Offset.top when lined up to the top of the screen?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, wordpress-theming

I am trying to get css animations to go off correctly when the page is scrolled to each element and so I have used this jquery as an example:

```
// element animation scroll detection
(function ($, document, undefined) {
    var animation1 = $('.animation1').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var winHeight = $(window).height();

        if(winTop >= (animation1-winHeight)){
        $('.animation1').addClass("animate-from-left");
        }

        $('.scrollTop').html("scrollTop: "+winTop);
        $('.elementOffset-top').html(" element Offset.top: "+animation1);
    });
})(jQuery, document);
```

Here is the live version of this to see: http://bbmthemes.com/themes/smart/

.animation1 is the div for the first animation.  Directly above that div I have used jquery to output the value of the Offset.top of animation1 as well as the value of scrollTop, which updates as you scroll.

What I cannot understand is, why when I scroll so that the jquery variable outputs are right at the very top edge of the screen does it say that the scrollTop distance is ~430px more than the Offset.top of div.animation1 which  is basically touching the top edge of the screen?

This is totally throwing off when to trigger the animations and I can't get them to work consistently when they are on different parts of the page because the difference in those two values keeps changing.

I tried to put this into a jsfiddle but I just cannot get the problem to replicate the same way.  Here is a very messy version but the values aren't quite the same on the output: http://jsfiddle.net/UsgNY/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation1 variable is never updated, even though the layout seems to be dynamically changed. The result is that animation1 holds the offset of how animation1 was put initially. To solve it, you simply have to set the variable locally to be initialized every time the page is scrolled. Like this:

```
// element animation scroll detection
(function ($, document, undefined) {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var winHeight = $(window).height();
        var animation1 = $('.animation1').offset().top;

        if(winTop >= (animation1-winHeight)){
        $('.animation1').addClass("animate-from-left");
        }

        $('.scrollTop').html("scrollTop: "+winTop);
        $('.elementOffset-top').html(" element Offset.top: "+animation1);
    });
})(jQuery, document);
```

You could of course use a global variable that is updated every time the layout changes, but I find this solution easier.

Here is a corrected jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gL2y4/